# jquery plugin to capture user input via virtual keyboard

Tags: jquery

Most of the bank sites have a keyboard (primarily with alphabets) which let them select user input (usually for their passwords). Is there a jquery plugin available which we can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery/

But I think it would be a lot of fun to have a go at making one yourself. Should be as easy as a loop that assigns key codes to some divs and a function that writes the value of those key codes in a chosen field.